# Can I use the reverse geocoding server side, e.g. with C# or C++?

Tags: c#, c++, google-maps

Can I use the reverse geocoding server side, e.g. with a C#  or C++?

**EDIT: I get some list of longititudes and latitudes from GPS Mouse, And I need to find all the corresponds addresses and save it to database. I am not interested to show on a map.**

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What's the use case?

Comment: Post exactly what you're trying to do and where you have problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you display the results on a google map and stay within 2,500 requests per day, sure (100,000 if you have Google Maps API Premier).  Note, though, and I quote from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be
>   used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   geocoding results without displaying
>   them on a map is prohibited. For
>   complete details on allowed usage,
>   consult the [Maps API Terms of Service
>   License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12).

If you satisfy the restrictions, [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) is easy from anywhere -- e.g., and again I quote:

> the following query contains the
>   latitude/longitude value for a
>   location in Brooklyn:
>   http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
>   Note: Ensure that no space exists
>   between the latitude and longitude
>   values when passed in the latlng
>   parameter.

If you can't abide by the Google Maps geocoding API restrictions, why not get such services e.g from [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah try this [Google Geo Kit](http://gglgeo.codeplex.com/)